# Gupta/Centura to Java conversion

Tags: java, guptateamdeveloper

We are working with a client who wants to convert from Gupta/Centura to Java. Has anyone got any experience with a conversion project like that?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

Concur with Clint below.   Consider Centura ( now TeamDeveloper ) v6.1 ( TD.Net is No Longer Beta ) .  Gives all the usual Win32 functionality and more, with open native connectivity to most dBMS ( avoiding ODBC) , but with the option to infuse very easily with .Net  .   Also allows a Centura app to be built as a Web Service, and also includes fab wizards to allow easy Web Service consumption.   That way - there may be no need for conversion to Java, which sounds like a re-write rather than a straight conversion.
Consider WHY you want to convert to Java - as you may get much more ROI on converting to TD.Net v6.1 !   There is HEAPS of help doing this - on the user forum - check out [Unify Centura User forums](http://support.unify.com/supportforum/)

Comment: Consider an upgrade to TeamDeveloper v7 , which has native 64 bit run-time , and many, many new features that may overcome the desire to re-write. Beware greatly the auto-convert tools - bad experiences of blowing out the budget and have having to write it all off in the end.  An eventual upgrade to TD7 way exceeded all expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Centura to Java I have not heard about but I do know there are conversions to the latest Centura version (6.0 and 6.1 in beta) which allow you to go to .NET and very easily integrate .NET.

See http://www.unify.com/Products/App_Dev/TeamDeveloper6.0/default.aspx for more information

While this does not answer your question perhaps it will aid you in any way.

Comment: To clarify - To migrate from Gupta ( Centura ) TeamDeveloper v6 Win32 to Gupta TeamDeveloper v6.Net or TD v7.Net , is considered a 'Project' and is in no way automatable. You must first purchase the correct TeamDeveloper compiler ( its considered a License change ) . Go here to get an overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhPPH5gg_G8

Answer (score 0):

My Company did migrate over the last year, our product to c#.net.
we used as far Gupta 3.1 and now we've got c#.net code, we did this with [fecher.eu](http://www.fecher.eu)

but i do recommend to start over with the project because:

- your Code will be cleaner (all the forbidden stuff they did in gupta will not be there)
- you got a better architecture (your own)
- you can migrate one tool(program) step by step...

i hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

We migrated too using ice tea group tools, probably the same tools used by fecher.eu. In our case we started to rewrite but we had too much code and after almost 1 year of rewrite we only did 20% of the code and it was too risky to keep going. We were introducing a ton of new bugs too!

The automated conversion did the entire code set (3.5M SAL Lines) in 6 months and we released in 6 more months!

The generated code was not the perfect code that we all set out to write and dream of. But I can tell you that the code we write by hand wasn't that pretty either. ;)

Comment: You were one of the 'Lucky' ones.  Believe me - we learnt the hard way, that for every 1 successful 'automated conversion' there are 3 failed ones. You never hear about these through embarrassment.    We wasted $3m attempting both manual and auto-conversion, and in the end simply upgraded to a new version of Gupta TeamDeveloper - for about 1/10th the cost, and never looked back. You have been warned.

Comment: I have actually heard from at least 15 other companies that they migration from gupta to c# was successful and relatively inexpensive.

Comment: And I have heard from at least 15 others that wish they hadn't tried, as was far tooo expensive ( usually tax-payers money being squandered ), and dubious result. Maybe they were being too fussy I guess.